# Crash on iOS7.1 When chose Enable Address Sanitizer in Xcode7

Tags: xcode7, ios7.1

I want to know what would cause this. Crash log:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

in **Release** environment close AddressSenitizer  ，good luck to you